# Python plotting lines parallel to y axis from array

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook

I have an array containing 5 different numbers:

`array([2.40064633, 4.10132553, 8.59968518, 2.40290345, 1.39988773]`

and I want to plot the lines on the x axis (parallel to the y axis) equal to each of these numbers i.e.

`x = 2.4006463`
`x = 4.10132553` so on and so forth for all of the numbers in the array.

I tried using `plot(x = array[...])` but to no solution.

Is there a clean way of doing this using numpy or mathlab?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
b =([2.40064633, 4.10132553, 8.59968518, 2.40290345, 1.39988773])

for l in b:
    plt.axvline(l)

plt.show()
```

or is it an numpy array then:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(1,4)
for l in x:
    plt.axvline(l)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my take. quite the similar as Rahul's only with the lines harshed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
xcoords = np.array([2.40064633, 4.10132553, 8.59968518, 2.40290345, 1.39988773])
for xc in xcoords:
    plt.axvline(x=xc, color='k', linestyle='--')
```

[image]